# Unable to add a second router-outlet in a parent component.html for showing a nested child in routing

Tags: angular, routes

I have an angular version(11) app,
an app.module which imports the app.routing.module.ts where i have defined all the routes,
here is the code of routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { EditOrDeleteComponent } from './main/editOrDelete/edit-or- 
delete.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: MainComponent},
{
path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { animation: 'home' }, 
children: [
{path: '', component: EditOrDeleteComponent}
]
},
 { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, data: { animation: 
'about' } },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And App.module

```
 import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
 browser/animations';
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

 import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
 import { AppComponent } from './app.component';




  @NgModule({
         declarations: [
         AppComponent,
         ],

        imports: [
          BrowserModule,
          BrowserAnimationsModule,
          AppRoutingModule
          ],
          providers: [],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent]
          })
          export class AppModule { }
```

In the HomeComponent html file i need a second router-outlet for showing the child component EditOrDeleteComponent, but i get the error of "'router-outlet' is not a known element:

1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module."
   everytime that i try to add the second `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
   it has been 4 hours i am trying to understand this issue,
   Can anyone help me please,

Comment: Have you added 'AppRoutingModule' in your AppModule imports[] array?

Comment: Zam Abdul Vahid, All imports and exports are perfectly correct , just the error appear on adding the second router-outlet to the parent component’s html

Comment: Give a path to the child route and see is it works {path: 'edit', component: EditOrDeleteComponent}

Comment: I tried every possible way, but no luck...

Comment: Can you update the question with the whole app module and router module code

Comment: I updated it with the both module code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to register the components inside declarations[] array in router module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { EditOrDeleteComponent } from './main/editOrDelete/edit-or- delete.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: MainComponent},
    { path: 'home', 
      component: HomeComponent, 
      data: { animation: 'home' }, 
      children: [
          {path: '', component: EditOrDeleteComponent}
      ]
    },
    { path: 'about', 
      component: AboutComponent, 
      data: { animation: 'about' } 
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: [HomeComponent, AboutComponent, MainComponent, EditOrDeleteComponent]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-to3v9f?file=src/app/app.routing.module.ts

Comment: @Riaz Glad i could help. It would be great if you can mark the answer as accepted as it would help other community members we well who faces similar issues

Comment: @Riaz Ignore those @Inputs() as I forked the project from one of my previous work to quickly show the router changes :)